# #kentico cms to salesforce community

Tags: salesforce, saml, kentico

We have a website running on Kentico. When a user logs in there will be a link available for the user to navigate to a Salesforce Community. When the user clicks the link I would like to automatically log the user into the Salesforce Community. My Kentico Users as in sync with the Salesforce contacts/external users.

Has anyone implemented this? If so, can you share how you achieved? It seems like a SAML Assertion needs to be generated and posted but I am not familiar with how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since Kentico should not be used as the authentication provider for other applications, it will be easier for you to find out can SF Community provide some authentication API which then you can setup custom external authentication (through SF) in Kentico.

You can also consider using something like OpenID which is supported by both SF and Kentico. (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_authentication_options.htm&type=0)

Comment: This community link will only show for about 20 users right now. I don't want to implement a different form of authentication to accommodate a small percentage of users. Am I wrong in thinking that I could dynamically generate a SAML with the subject being the users federated id that I have from Salesforce?

Comment: are you talking about generate a SAML using Kentico API for SF to use? Maybe, but no one I know has done that before.

Comment: It doesn't have to be class within Kentico. On click of that link, I can query the user table in Kentico to get the users federated id and then somehow start to build the SAML file to post. It is the "somehow start to build a SAML file" part that I don't know how to do. Can this be done in asp.net? If so, I am looking for some short code from someone that has done this type of thing.